# Style attribute attr/@attr/minTextSize not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I have trying since long to identify the issue but unfortunately not able to

If I do

> android.enableAapt2=true

The code works fine, but removing the same(Which should compulsorily be) there is a error thrown saying

```
\incremental\mergeDevDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5887: error: style attribute 'attr/@attr/minTextSize' not found.
```

Here are the details of the versions I am using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1"
```

In Gradle.Propeties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip
```

Support Library version

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

error outputpath

```
\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\33e6fcc6d3eea5b57de6d7aedf3f55c0\res\values\values.xml
```

Comment: Test case try to update `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'`

Comment: It didn't help.Also 28.0.0 is stable release hence alpha won't help.

Comment: add your compileSdkVersion

Comment: Have you tried to clean project? You can try also reload project, maybe this is some cache problem. Close your project, go to the project folder and delete .gradle, .idea, build and app/build folders. (Also you may to remove the project from recent) In AS click on Open existing project, and open it (or import). If this is because of the cache it will solve your problem

Comment: Did you use `minTextSize`? If yes, can we see how you used it inside the styles? It looks weird: `attr/@attr/minTextSize` maybe a clean project?

Comment: @Pavya compileSdkVersion 28 I am using.

Comment: @Mohsen I do not use anywhere.

Comment: @dantes_21 I have tried multiple times. Removing from recent I need to give a try.

Comment: So if you really sure that your resources is ok here, I can suggest the extra cleaning)) You need to remove .gradle folder from your User folder (before that you of course have to close AS) in my example its C:\\Users\[my name]\.gradle. This trick will remove all gradle cache from all projects and all your libraries, you need to download it again (When you next time open AS it will download it automatically, but its will take a lot of time (it will download all your library again even android.support libraries))

Comment: @dantes_21 Still the same.

Comment: Still stuck on the same.Is the more info I need to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with some of the gradles added in project.
Actually the libraries internally have defined the attribute `minTextSize`

Due to latest updates and compatibility the `attr` was not found.

To identify I have defined same attr as

```
<attr name="minTextSize" format="integer">16</attr>
```

in `attrs.xml` in my app module.
Compiling the same thrown error of duplicate value and path and from that path I have found the library which needs to be updated.

Updating to the latest of all library version have solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in my case it happened when i upgraded build tools, to resolve this issue,
you should have two attr files like in this image:[image]

Add these lines in **both of attr.xml** files:

```
 <style name="SquareTextView">
         <item name="minTextSize">5dp</item>
    </style>
    <declare-styleable name="SquareTextView"><attr format="dimension" name="minTextSize"/></declare-styleable>
```

This resolved the issue i was facing. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have attrs.xml, then create one. After that add this snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
           <style name="SquareTextView">
               <item name="minTextSize">5dp</item>
           </style>
           <declare-styleable name="SquareTextView">
             <attr format="dimension" name="minTextSize"/>
           </declare-styleable>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Could you also explain what that snippet does and why it solves the problem?

Comment: Since, it happens because you have added some of the older version of dependency in your project which affect your Text view properties.