# Android resource compilation failed after gradle updation to 3.3.0 alpha13

Tags: android, android-resources

Android resource compilation after update gradle to 3.3.0 alpha13.

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevelopmentDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1984: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTint' with config ''.

D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevelopmentDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1984: error: resource previously defined here.


D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevelopmentDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2128: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTint' with config ''.

D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevelopmentDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2128: error: resource previously defined here.

D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevelopmentDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2131: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTintMode' with config ''.

D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDevelopmentDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2131: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: C:\Users\CS1138\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\90dfe495736790be8f2d7ece9df5d6ca\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\Development\debug \
        D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental
```

Comment: What was your previous gradle version?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need an alpha release?

Comment: go to this path `D:\projects\envoy-android\app\build` delete every folder in it and rebuild your project

Comment: Just for your reference please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698540/style-attribute-attr-attr-mintextsize-not-found

Comment: i have deleted build folder .gradle , even then i hve same issue